# The choice of cofibrant approximation is contractible

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $ \mathcal{M} $ be a model category and $ A $ a object of $ \mathcal{M} $.
The "choice category" $ \mathcal{C} $ of cofibrant approximations of $ A $
is the full subcategory of $ \mathcal{M}_{/A} $ such that
$ X \to A \in \operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{C} $ if and only if $ X \to A $ is a weak equivalence and $ X $ is cofibrant.

How can I prove that (the nerve of) $ \mathcal{C} $ is contractible?

Hirschhorn's book *"Model categories and their localizations"* has a
more general fact as Theorem 14.5.4, but
its proof seems to be incorrect.
(In his proof, $ (F\mathbf{X}, p_{\mathbf{X}}) $ can be not terminal.)

**Edit**:
I require the factorizations are *functorial* as in the book of Hirschhorn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the full subcategory W(M/A)⊂M/A
consisting of objects that are weak equivalences in M.
The latter category in its turn has a full subcategory C(W(M/A))
consisting of objects with a cofibrant source.
The inclusion functor C(W(M/A))→W(M/A)
and the cofibrant replacement functor W(M/A)→C(W(M/A))
(induced from the cofibrant replacement functor on the model category M/A)
induce an equivalence on nerves:
the composition K: W(M/A)→C(W(M/A))→W(M/A) admits a natural
weak equivalence K→id
and the composition L: C(W(M/A))→W(M/A)→C(W(M/A)) admits
a natural weak equivalence L→id.
Thus the nerve of C(W(M/A)) is equivalent to the nerve
of W(M/A), and the latter is contractible because it admits
a natural weak equivalence id→const_1, where 1 is the terminal object.

Comment: id: A -> A is not a object of C unless A is already cofibrant.

Comment: @B.W.: Sorry, I left out the part of the argument that reduces to the case of cofibrant A.  Fixed now.

Comment: In the edited answer, how can I get that the pullback functor sends cofibrant to cofibrant?

Comment: @B.W.: The pullback functor does not preserve cofibrancy.  I added a paragraph that explains this.

Comment: What do you mean by “by virtue of a cofibrant replacement functor”? I cannot understand this part. If this is true, we don’t need A’ because W(M/A) is contractible.

Comment: @B.W.: I added details about the cofibrant replacement functor.

Comment: Now it seems to be correct. Thank you!